# symfony flex with private recipes

Tags: composer-php, symfony4, symfony-flex

What's the proper way to setup a flex recipe (private or public repository) for a package (private repository)?

**What I tried so far**

Got a private repository on bitbucket with a package.
Got a private repository on github with recipes.
Configured symfony flex server on github repository.
Added projects ids in config.json (recipes repository)

Yet, I can't understand how a recipe gets called during composer update..

Comment: What exactly is happening now when you try to install the package? Is the package installed at all? Is it just the recipe that isn't applied? Did you register yourself for the private recipes beta?